# Automatically load cdc-acm at boot

Tags: 12.04, boot, bash, gnome-terminal, modules

Hi I am trying to figure out how I can load the `cdc-acm` module at boot. I tried this command:

`sudo bash -c echo hoi >> /etc/modules`

but I get this:

`bash: /etc/modules: Permission denied`

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo -s
```

then

```
echo hoi >> /etc/modules
```